# Image alt attribute

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, editor, text

My images have alt attribute, but is not showing. My SEO pluging does not recognized them and google prensets the an alt text that is not the one I wrote but the name of the picture(file).
this is how it I can see it in the backend:
[wpd_image_box thumbnail= .....
If I change it to 
[vc_single_image image=
then the seo pluging, will reconizg it, but I will loose the theme in it.

Comment: You'll have to look at the implementations of the wpd_image_box and vc_single_image shortcodes and the HTML they generate. AFAIK they aren't default WordPress shortcodes: you must be using a plugin that defines them?

Comment: Yes, i think the WPBakery page builder. I believe this plugin might be causing the problem.

Comment: do you think, this problem could be solved by updating the plugin?